# Default OnChange Event JavaScript function to check input field is Number or Letter for all the input number fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have around 30 input fields which take a number as input. Is there any way to write a single default OnChange event JavaScript function for all the number input fields instead of writing 30 JavaScript functions to check whether the entered input is a number or text? and If the input is NaN I need to add the red colored border to that input field. Thank you. Sorry for not adding the code for the first time.

HTML Code

```
<tr>
<td>
Fund1:<input type="text" class="" name="FundAmount1" id="Fund1" onchange="ValidateIsNaN()" />
</td>
<td>
Fund2:<input type="text" class="" name="FundAmount2" id="Fund2" />
</td>
<td>
Fund3:<input type="text" class="" name="FundAmount3" id="Fund3"/>
</td>
<td>
Fund4:<input type="text" class="" name="FundAmount4" id="Fund4"/>
</td>
<td>
Fund5:<input type="text" class="" name="FundAmount5" id="Fund5" />
</td>
.
.
.
Total:<input type="text" class="" name="Total" id="TotalId" />
</tr>
```

JavaScript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateIsNaN(){
var inputValue = document.getElementByName('Fund1').value;
if (isNaN(inputValue )) 
{
    $("Fund1").addClass("redColorBorderCSS");
            alert("Enter number only")
            return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please always, always, always include the relevant code you are working with (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript)

Comment: Sorry, Scott Marcus. I just added the code.

Comment: Why not just use `<input type="number">`?

Comment: If I put `<input type="number">` it is not allowing me to enter decimal values. If I enter 15.55 the error it is showing me in Chrome is "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest values are 15 and 16".

Comment: `input type=number` allows decimal input. You must have some other code conflicting with it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for your reply. I don't have any other code. I'm getting this "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest values are 15 and 16" error only when I  click the submit button. And, I have not write any onsubmit or onclick JavaScript function to this form.

Comment: You must not be configuring the `input` with [a `step` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step), as in: `<input type="number" min="1" max="10" step=".1">` See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whu4s3fz/2/) for an example.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you for your time.  `<td>
Amount:
<input type="number"  name="FundAmount1" id="FundAmount1Id"/>
</td>`  this is the html for the field that I'm using in the form. I'm not using 'step' attribute. To be honest I don't even know about `step` attribute tille now.

Comment: I've provided a link to the documentation where you can read about `step`. So add that attribute and your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you so much @ScottMarcus. `<input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="0.01">` is working fine in chrome and other browsers except IE 9.0 or below versions.

Comment: That's because IE 9 doesn't support most of HTML5, which is what `type=number` is. Do you really need to support an 8 year old browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly test for numbers in a lot of different ways.

1. Use the `<input type="number">` HTML element
2. In your onChange event you can `var result = parseInt(value, 10)` or `var result = parseFloat(value, 10)` and test with `isNaN(result)`
3. You can write a regular expression to validate the input value `/^[0-9]+$/` or `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/`

Comment: Thank you for the reply @j3e8. Is there any way to write a common function to check all the number input fields. Thank you.

Comment: [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) doesn't have a second argument for the radix.